# .describe method gives result as another data type compares to describe() in pandas regarding date-time format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, anaconda, datetime-format

When I check with `data.describe` it shows date time format where as when I check through .describe() method, It gives data type as object type. What is the problem?

```
data['Date'].describe()

count                     494
unique                    494
top       2017-10-30 00:00:00
freq                        1
first     2017-05-15 00:00:00
last      2019-05-13 00:00:00
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

```
data['Date'].describe

<bound method NDFrame.describe of 0     2017-05-15
1     2017-05-16
2     2017-05-17
3     2017-05-18
4     2017-05-19
         ...    
491   2019-05-07
492   2019-05-08
493   2019-05-09
494   2019-05-10
495   2019-05-13
Name: Date, Length: 494, dtype: datetime64[ns]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**df.describe()** : calls the method and returns the result.

**df.describe**   : is the method itself (you can think of a 'pointer to method' in some other languages)

```
> p = df.describe 
> p()

> df.describe()
```

Both p() and df.describe() gives same result.

I will recommand you use `df.info()` if you want to check type of all the columns.

Comment: Thank you for info, It was actually showing type of info shown in pointer method, i understand now.